# Is K = 1 is good for KNN, when error is min, accuracy is max and even AUROC is Max for that value of K?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I am getting highest Accuracy for K =1 in KNN, Max AUROC, and lowest Error. however, I was taught that when K = 1, then its always going to be over-fitting mode, and hence I am asking the question is it good or not?

Even when I tried with validation set, and below are the Graphs for the Validation set and test set for k = 1 to 25.

**Legend for Graphs: Blue line is Validation set, Green Line is Test Set**

[image: Error Rate for Valid and Test set]

[image: Accuracy for Valid and Test set]

[image: AUROC for Valid and Test set]

Please do let me know is K= 1 is good?

**Note: I tried five classification Algorithms(GNB, Decision Tree, LogReg, KNN and LDA), from which KNN is showing best accuracy and lease error and hence I am working on KNN.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error rate at K=1 is always zero for the training sample. This is because the closest point to any training data point is itself. Hence it'll always overfit.
You should try out different K values on a validation set and plot the validation error. See where it becomes lowest over time as you increase K.

---

At K=1, you were overfitting the boundaries. Hence, validation error rate initially decreases and reaches a minima. After the minima point, it then increase with increasing K. To get the optimal value of K, you can segregate the training and validation from the initial dataset. Now plot the validation error curve to get the optimal value of K. This value of K should be used for all predictions.

---

Your Auroc curve behaves similarly. Therefore it decreases at first and then it increases. From your curves of validation error as well as auroc , your ideal K lies somewhere between 20-25 as far as the K values are shown in the graph

Comment: Thanks for the explanation..!!